# How do I pass an array up to a higher scope

Tags: android, kotlin

Here is the start of my Android project

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    var (ngbpBoard, shipList) = initTheGame()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

I want the ngbpBoard array to be available for a click event and it isn't.

When I put a

```
var ngbpBoard = IntArray(100) { WATER }
```

statement at the top of the class, it overrides the one I created in initTheGame().

How do I pass this data up and back down again, please?

Comment: Shadowing is bad idea anyways, try not to name two variables exactly the same.

Comment: That's just it - they are not two variables they are the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to first initialize `ngbpBoard` in `onCreate`, then you can do something like:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    // Do not initialize yet
    private lateinit var ngbpBoard: IntArray

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val (ngbpBoard, shipList) = initGame()
        // Initialize this variable
        this.ngbpBoard = ngbpBoard
    }
}
```

Otherwise, if you want to initialize in the instance creation and just modify it in `onCreate`, just replace

```
private lateinit var ngbpBoard: IntArray
```

with

```
private var ngbpBoard: IntArray = IntArray(100) { WATER }
```